# How to delete duplicate data in mysql using cte

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression, window-functions

I want to delete duplicate data in my table. But my sql sript returns Error in query (1064).

I have tried two separate sql statements on my MySQL server but it keeps throwing the syntax error.

Table columns:

```
msisdn_lte
batch_id
file_id
date_key
call_timestamp
data_volume
da_value_before_call
da_value_after_call
served_account
source_file_nm
quote
pull_date_time
```

All which have the exact same data insert 2 times. I.E there is double of each distinct data

First statement

```
DELETE A
FROM
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY * ORDER BY call_timestamp) AS rn
FROM broadband_usage_history
) A
WHERE A.rn > 1;
```

Second statement

```
WITH usage_cte AS 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition  BY call_timestamp order by call_timestamp) AS row_number
    FROM broadband_usage_history
) 
SELECT * FROM usage_cte ;
```

I expect to get one input of each data in the table but i cant even get the query to run.

Comment: I haven't even looked at your query to see if any syntax errors stand out, but the first question is are you using MySQL 8.0.2 or later? That's when window functions like `ROW_NUMBER()` were first introduced. https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-2-introducing-window-functions/

Comment: How do you define "duplicate"? Should the data be equal in all columns, even in `call_timestamp`?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel duplicate in the sense that we have the same data in all columns

Answer (score 1):

If you can have duplicate rows with the same data in all columns, then there is no way to delete a row without deleting its duplicates. CTEs and ROW_NUMBER() will not help you in this case, because you can't delete from a CTE in MySQL. A JOIN with the CTE neither will help, since you have no identifying columns for the ON clause. I see two ways to solve your issue:

#### 1. Create a table copy

Create a new table with the same schema and copy only distinct data. Then drop the original table and rename the new one to replace it:

```
CREATE TABLE broadband_usage_history_distinct LIKE broadband_usage_history;

INSERT INTO broadband_usage_history_distinct
    SELECT DISTINCT * FROM broadband_usage_history;

DROP TABLE broadband_usage_history;

RENAME TABLE broadband_usage_history_distinct TO broadband_usage_history;
```

[Example on db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tsDBPwdBBjWSqbKTgZYA3b/0)

#### 2. Create a PRIMARY KEY

Your issue is one of the reasons, why it's advised always to define a primary key. The good news - It's never too late to create an AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY. After that you can use it as row identifier for a DELETE-JOIN query:

```
ALTER TABLE broadband_usage_history
  ADD id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;

WITH cte AS (
  SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY
      msisdn_lte,
      batch_id,
      file_id,
      date_key,
      call_timestamp,
      data_volume,
      da_value_before_call,
      da_value_after_call,
      served_account,
      source_file_nm,
      quote,
      pull_date_time
    ORDER BY id
  ) AS rn
  FROM broadband_usage_history
)
  DELETE t
  FROM cte
  JOIN broadband_usage_history t USING(id)
  WHERE rn > 1
;
```

[Example on db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7QvuCZEjoVdnsWKXmzfBmK/0)

You can also remove the duplicates in older versions without window functions using a GROUP BY subquery:

```
ALTER TABLE broadband_usage_history
  ADD id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;

DELETE t
FROM broadband_usage_history t
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT MIN(id) AS id
  FROM broadband_usage_history
  GROUP BY 
      msisdn_lte,
      batch_id,
      file_id,
      date_key,
      call_timestamp,
      data_volume,
      da_value_before_call,
      da_value_after_call,
      served_account,
      source_file_nm,
      quote,
      pull_date_time
) x USING (id)
WHERE x.id IS NULL;
```

[Example on db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k4NatVZXVEdUY2XJ6x4AfA/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can't Partition by all the columns, just change it to the columns should be unique. Also yu can't delete from a subquery.

```
   DELETE H
    FROM broadband_usage_history H
    INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Columns_Should_Be_Unique ORDER BY call_timestamp) AS rn
    FROM broadband_usage_history
    ) A
    ON A.Columns_Should_Be_Unique =H.Columns_Should_Be_Unique 
    WHERE A.rn > 1;
```

Comment: "You can't Partition by all the columns" - This is not accurate. You can partition by all columns if you list them all, but you cant partition by `*`. Also you can simplify the ON clause replacing it with `USING(Columns_Should_Be_Unique)`

Comment: That statement is in the context of removing duplicates. If you partition by all columns, you will not be able to get the row numbers for the duplicated  rows. But thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I understood that "duplicate" means same data in all columns. But then I saw `ORDER BY call_timestamp`, which wouldn't make sence. So I don't know now.

Comment: @PeterHe there really is no unique column, all data in the columns are the same. That is why i tried using the call time stamp but i keep getting syntax error from the partition query

Comment: @Tobbie I meant what columns should be unique.   They are duplicated now, but you want to remove the duplicated rows, which means some columns need to be unique, the worst scenario is all columns make the record unique.

Comment: @PeterHe all columns make it a unique record, but the call_timestamp can/should be different for each entry but can be the same for a different msisdn. I hope I have confused you.

Comment: OK, then you an just replace Columns_Should_Be_Unique  in my answer with the all the columns except call_timestamp. It should delete the duplicates. Otherwise please provide sample data.and expected results